# How to continue a code while a loop is already running

Tags: python, python-3.x, infinite-loop, running-other-programs

I created a code that shows a real time clock at the beginning (works by a loop and refreshing itself in every 1 sec using \r )
But I want to run the rest of the code while the clock is ticking (continuously). But this isn't going any further while the loop is running.
*I think there is no need to write the code of the clock.*

Comment: You can try multi-threading..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have a task running, while using another you can use multi-threading. This means you tell your processor two different tasks and it will be continued as long as you tell it to work. See here a post about [multithreading and multiprocessing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3044580/multiprocessing-vs-threading-python). You can use the thread function of python for this.

Here a small example:

```
import threading
import time
# Define a function for the thread
def print_time( threadName, delay):
   count = 0
   while count < 10:
      time.sleep(delay)
      count += 1
      print ("%s: %s" % ( threadName, time.ctime(time.time()) ))

def counter(threadName, number_of_counts, delay):
    count=0
    while count < number_of_counts:
        print ("%s: %s" % ( threadName, count))
        time.sleep(delay)
        count +=1
# Create two threads as follows
threading.Thread(target=print_time, args=("Thread-1", 1, )).start()
threading.Thread(target=counter, args=("Thread-2", 100, 0.1,)).start()
```

for further information check [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html). Note that `thread` has been renamed to `_thread` in python 3

Comment: I would recommend using `threading.Thread(target=print_time, args=("Thread-1", 1, )).start()` rather than using `start_new_thread`.

Comment: @DanD. you are right, `threading` might be the better solution here. changed it